# How to find server id with MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

MySQL manual holds that the function **UUID_SHORT()** is guaranteed to be unique if the following conditions hold (list not extensive):

1. The **server_id** of the current host is unique among your set of master and slave servers
2. **server_id** is between 0 and 255

I'm using **UUID_SHORT()** on several **MAMP** servers.

How do I set, or where can I see **server_id** value with **MAMP**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view system variables with [`SHOW VARIABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "server_id";
```

Since, [`server_id`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id) is dynamic, you can set the variable with [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html):

```
SET GLOBAL server_id=1
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I modify it though?